# Having trouble when trying to include boost.serialization into my VS project

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

So i want to get Boost.serialization into my project but i just want that library from the boost package that you get. I built the boost thing so got i got access to the .lib files for the serialization library.
The ones i got are;

```
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_55
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_55
libboost_wserialization-vc100-mt-1_55
libboost_wserialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_55
```

I took these and put them into a new folder and linked my VS project to these files to the additional lib directory.
I also took serialization folder from the boost package and put it in my include folder that is linked to my project.

When i now try to build my app i get these errors;

```
IntelliSense: cannot open source file "boost/config.hpp"
IntelliSense: cannot open source file "boost/operators.hpp"
IntelliSense: namespace "boost" has no member class "totally_ordered1"
```

How should i go about to fix these errors? Do i need to add all the .hpp files that the library wants or is there another way around this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you built boost and then moved some of the headers into your project. The latter is not advisable - leave the boost includes and libraries where you've installed them and built boost.

In Project ⇒ Properties ⇒ Configuration Properties, add

- The toplevel boost directory to the `Include Directories` (eg., c:\boost)
- The directory with the built boost libraries to the `Library Directories` (eg., c:\boost\lib)

If you still get IntelliSense errors after that add

- The "$(ProjectDir)" to the `Reference Directories`